# ValueError: logits and labels must have the same shape ((None, 2) vs (None, 1))

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, tensorflow, lstm

I was working with LSTMS to predict if we(the bot) should buy something based on 2 factors. So my X consists of an numpy array consisting of separate numpy arrays each with a numpy array of 2. Since that is confusing it looks like np.array(np.array(np.array([item,item]),np.array([item,item])),np.array(np.array([item,item]),np.array([item,item])))

My y values is a numpy array of a list of 0's and 1's. A sample of that is

```
[[1]
 [0]
 [0]
 ...
 [0]]
```

Here's my model

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(128,input_shape=(30,2),return_sequences=True))
model.add(Dropout(0.1))

model.add(LSTM(128,return_sequences=True))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))

model.add(LSTM(128))
model.add(Dropout(0.1))

model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(64,activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(2,activation='softmax'))
model.compile(optimizer='adam',loss='binary_crossentropy',metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit(seqs,buy_sell,epochs=200,callbacks=[tensboard])
```

and my traceback

```
ValueError: logits and labels must have the same shape ((None, 2) vs (None, 1))
```

I was thinking of reshaping my X/y but wouldn't that affect the model. How would I go about fixing this?

Does the loss function have anything to do with this?

Comment: could you print part of your y array?

Comment: ok, then you need to change the shape of last dense layer to 1. and instead of softmax use sigmoid for activation.

Comment: also, you don't need the flatten layer. LSTM output is flat when return_sequence is false.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add to my comments, if you want to stick to `softmax` activation for any reason (you may have more classes in future), then modify the last line of code like this:

```
model.fit(seqs, tf.keras.utils.to_categorical(buy_sell,  num_classes=2), epochs=200, callbacks=[tensboard])
```